# Can't Open SSRS Reports

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have inherited an SSRS solution that I can't seem to work with.  I sat down with the previous owner briefly and he showed me where in TFS to find the solution.  The also opened up a few of the RDL files and attempted to give me the gist of modifying a report.  Every thing seemed straight forward to me during that session.

Now the original developer is gone and I now have access to the code in TFS.  Whenever I try to open one of the RDL files, it opens it up as an XML document instead of opening it in the designer.

I have Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Management studio installed.  Any thoughts on what I may be missing like service packs or hot fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-run the SQL Server 2008 installer on your machine.  You need to install the Business Intelligence Developer Studio component, or whatever it was called in '08.

If you don't have access to an installer, find the SQL Server Express with Advanced Services download (whatever year you need, just make sure it's the "Advanced Services" - here's 2008:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842 ), and run that; it will also provide an option for BIDS.

Comment: Bless you :)
I was thinking it might be something like that.  I'm not sure but I think that the SQL Server might be running SP2.  Does that matter?

Comment: Well let's be clear first:

If the SQL Server instance is 2008, running *Service Pack* 2, then the tools will be fine, though you might want to grab SP2 and apply it yourself.

If the SQL Server instance is *2008 R2*, then you'll want the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition download, not just vanilla 2008.

2008 R2 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438